# OpenCV3.2 VideoWriter in Android

Tags: android, opencv

I am using the OpenCV 3.2 Library for Android in my project to save video,but it not work, no error,and no file.
It's my code in `onCameraFrame`:

```
     if (isRecord) {
        if (mVideoWriter == null) {
            mVideoWriter = new VideoWriter(recordfilepath(), VideoWriter.fourcc('M','J','P','G'), 15, mRgba.size());
        }
        if (!mVideoWriter.isOpened()) {
            mVideoWriter.open(recordfilepath(), VideoWriter.fourcc('M','J','P','G'), 15, mRgba.size());
        }

        if (!mVideoWriter.isOpened()) {
            Log.w(TAG, "onCameraFrame: open fail!");
        }

        mVideoWriter.write(mRgba);
    }
```

It's seems mVideoWriter is not open.
So,how can I record video use Opencv3.2 VideoWriter?

Thank you for your help!

**update：**
I change the filename from `.mp4` to `.avi`, then it worked! But the file has no sound and the screen is black, I don't know why.

PS: My english is so poor.. friend..?

**update2:**
I succeed. It's my code:

```
    if (isRecord) {

        Log.w(TAG, "onCameraFrame: 录制");
        if (mVideoWriter == null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "onCameraFrame: 初始化");
            //'P','I','M','1'
            // 'M','P','E','G'
            // 'M','J','P','G'
            mVideoWriter = new VideoWriter(recordfilepath(), VideoWriter.fourcc('M', 'J', 'P', 'G'), 25.0D, mRgba.size());
            mVideoWriter.open(recordfilepath(), VideoWriter.fourcc('M', 'J', 'P', 'G'), 25.0D, mRgba.size());
            Log.i(TAG, "onCameraFrame: recordFilePath" + recordfilepath());
        }
        if (!mVideoWriter.isOpened()) {
            Log.w(TAG, "onCameraFrame: open");
            mVideoWriter.open(recordfilepath(), VideoWriter.fourcc('M', 'J', 'P', 'G'), 25.0D, mRgba.size());
        }

        mVideoWriter.write(mRgba);
        Log.w(TAG, "onCameraFrame: 写入中 " + mRgba.toString());
    } else {
        if (mVideoWriter != null) {
            mVideoWriter.release();
        }
    }


    private String recordfilepath() {
    //        ongetTime();
    File sddir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File vrdir = new File(sddir, folder_name);
    mTimeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    File file = new File(vrdir, "KLI_" + mTimeStamp + ".avi");
    String filepath = file.getAbsolutePath();
    Log.e("debug mediarecorder", filepath);
    return filepath;
}
```

Comment: The only thing the constructor does is [call `open(...)`](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/45e18eed294c9365c443cce0824e5275708c2423/modules/videoio/src/cap.cpp#L725), so that second attempt at doing the same thing seems rather pointless. | Is the path correct? Did you try other codecs?

Comment: @DanMašek The path is "/storage/emulated/0/KLI/Video/KLI_20170116_104942.mp4",it seems true.I tried with no success: 'MPEG', 'MP4V', 'PIM1', 'VP80'.

Comment: I change `.mp4` to `.avi`, and set codecs is `MJPG`, then the file is create, but it has no sound and the screen is black.

Comment: Hi, did you succeed with it? I am stuck at the same point. Only succeeded creating the file using this extension and fourcc codec. But throws error  when trying to play it.

Comment: @JordiC.Yes, I succeed. See update2.

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
cv::VideoWriter writer;
writer.open("your_mp4_file_path.mp4", cv::VideoWriter::fourcc('H', '2', '6', '4'),
                    15, //framerate
                    cv::Size(720, 1280),
                    true);
writer << mat_frame;

// remember writer.release() when finish
```

Android platform, opencv4.5.2 with ffmpeg + openh264, work well for me